# Meteor.js app can't launch | "You are attempting to run Meteor as the 'root' superuser..."

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, web

I am getting this message in my server's console when trying to run meteor.

[image: warning screenshot]

How to resolve it?

Interesting, but it was working one hour ago, then I rebooted the server and this error appears.

Comment: Any reason for running meteor in development mode on a server instead of a built bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I tryied tgis flag to meteor launch command :

--allow-superuser

And it's seemed to be working!

**One more, better way to resolve it :**

I fixed that problem.
For security reasons meteor asks u to work from other user, not root.
so, add new user ( ubuntu )

`sudo adduser username`

after creation - authorize in:

`su - username`

Comment: Meh. This feels like treating symptoms instead of the root cause.

Comment: yeah, updated answer